# How to stop showing tutorial/walkthrough screen once user has signed up?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I'm trying to develop an app where user has to sign up.

I'm showing the walkthrough/tutorial screens only the first time user install & launch the app.

I want that once the user has signed up, the walkthroughs/tutorials should be stopped being displayed, but they are stopped getting displayed after the very first time whether the user has signed up or not.

How to write the code so that the walkthroughs/tutorials should stop being displayed only after the user has signed up.

Here's my Walkthroughs.java file's code:

```
public class Walkthroughs extends AppCompatActivity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    Button buttonSignUp;
    View view;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_walkthroughs);

        SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
            ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
            ed.apply();
        }

        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        CirclePageIndicator circleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);
        circleIndicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_walkthrough_screen_no1, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            switch (position){
                case 0:
                    return new Walkthroughs_screen_no1();
                case 1:
                    return new Walkthrough_screen_no2();
                case 2:
                    return new Walkthrough_screen_no3();
                case 3:
                    return new Walkthrough_screen_no4();
                case 4:
                    return new Walkthrough_screen_no5();
                default:
                    return new Walkthrough_screen_no5();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 5 total pages.
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase(l);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase(l);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_walkthrough_screen_no1, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's my Walkthrough_screen_no5.java file's code:

```
public class Walkthrough_screen_no5 extends Fragment {

    View view;
    Button buttonSignUp;
    EditText et;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_walkthrough_screen_no5, container, false);
        et = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.signUp_phoneNumber);
        buttonSignUp = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp);
        buttonSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String editText = et.getText().toString();
                if(editText.isEmpty()) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    builder.setTitle("Oops!");
                    builder.setMessage("You forgot to enter your phone number.");
                    builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                    dialog.show();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Here's my AndroidManifest.xml file's code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.abc.xxx" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyCredits"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_credits"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.abc.xxx.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".AddMoreFriends"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_friends"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.abc.xxx.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:parentActivityName=".Main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.abc.xxx.Main" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Help"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_help"
            android:parentActivityName=".Settings" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.abc.xxx.Settings" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Walkthroughs"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/WalkthroughThemes"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**I'm new to StackOverflow, so please cooperate.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No doubt you somewhere have a "finishTutorial" or similar method. Just call that when needed.

Comment: @Stultuske How to do that?

Comment: if (userWantsToQuitTutorial ){ quitTutorial(); }

Comment: @Stultuske hey buddy, I'm a beginner to Android Development, so can you please tell me where & how to declare this method?

Comment: You are aware it's your code we are talking about, right? you don't "have to" declare it in a specific place, it just has to do the trick.

Comment: If you declared a method which starts tutorial in one of the classes, I'm pretty sure that in the same class you can create quit method.

Answer (score 0):

Ok in this block of code

```
SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("ActivityPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(pref.getBoolean("activity_executed", false)){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = pref.edit();
        ed.putBoolean("activity_executed", true);
        ed.apply();
    }
```

you are checking for if activity_executed boolean and based on it's value you are deciding weather to launch your main activity but from next time onwards it will be always true you need to set the shared-preference "has_signedup" which should be set up in your Walkthrough_screen_no5 Fragment simmilarly the way you are doing and check that value in your Activity.